# TensorFlow Keras model cannot be loaded into Deeplearning4J due to custom layer

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, keras, deeplearning4j

I have trained a TensorFlow Keras model in Python and saved it as trained_model.h5:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4",
                                            output_shape = [1280],
                                            trainable = False),
                                            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
                                            tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_generator.num_classes, activation='softmax')
                             ])

model.build([None, 224, 224, 3])
model.summary()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'])

steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(train_generator.samples /train_generator.batch_size)
val_steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(valid_generator.samples/valid_generator.batch_size)
hist = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=3,
    verbose=1,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch).history
```

Then I want to load the trained model into my Java application by using Deeplearning4J version 1.0.0-beta7:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  String simpleMlp = new ClassPathResource("trained_model.h5").getFile().getPath();
  MultiLayerNetwork model = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(simpleMlp);

  String imagePath = new ClassPathResource("image.png").getFile().getPath();
  File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
  ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(height, width, channels);
  INDArray image = imageLoader.asRowVector(imageFile);

  INDArray outut = model.output(image);
}
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.exceptions.UnsupportedKerasConfigurationException: Unsupported keras layer type KerasLayer. Please file an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues.
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.utils.KerasLayerUtils.getKerasLayerFromConfig(KerasLayerUtils.java:334)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModel.prepareLayers(KerasModel.java:218)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasSequentialModel.<init>(KerasSequentialModel.java:110)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasSequentialModel.<init>(KerasSequentialModel.java:57)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.utils.KerasModelBuilder.buildSequential(KerasModelBuilder.java:322)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(KerasModelImport.java:223)
```

I believe this has to do with the custom KerasLayer where I use the mobilenet_v2 feature vector.
Is there a way I can fix this in order for me to load my model in my Java application?

Comment: Have you tried it to register as a custom layer with `KerasLayer.registerCustomLayer()`?

Comment: @Frightera no idea how to fo that for this scenario. You know how?

Comment: I misinterpreted the exception, sorry I've no idea.

Comment: Hi, I responded to you over on our issue tracker. If you can give me the model, I can help you figure out what you need to do.

Comment: @AdamGibson that would be great, thanks! Here is my trained model: https://glennboudaer.stackstorage.com/s/p0DYuJFuagaE9uSH

Comment: @AdamGibson I'll also provide the Tensorflow layer json file, where each layer of the model can be viewed https://glennboudaer.stackstorage.com/s/pHIHwHZWZ5sepiax